# Intellij IDEA: Scala Worksheet misbehaving

Tags: scala, logging, intellij-idea, typesafe

I'd like to test the `Scala` code that I've just written by running small fragments of it separately in a `Scala Worksheet`. What sounds like a trivial affair isn't working because:

1. After updating the code, the `Scala Worksheet` **keeps running the obsolete code**. I've already ticked the `Make Project` *checkbox* and have even tried the enabling `Use REPL Mode` without luck. When even a complete cycle of `sbt reload` > `sbt update` > `sbt clean` > `sbt compile` doesn't fix the issue, I wonder what will.
2. Even if I manage to fix the above issue, next thing is that I'm unaware of any possible way to **view the log messages** generated by `typesafe Logger` within `IntelliJ IDEA`. There might be some file where these logs are being *dumped* but leaving the *IDE* to view log file sounds *less-than-ideal* in 2018. The only other alternative would be to manually replace (or augment) each log line throughout my project with `println`. Something makes me think that there's got to be a better way. The `IntelliJ` docs page for [Setting Log Options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html) isn't very helpful as it is outdated and I cannot find the same UI as shown in the screenshots over there
3. Assuming above two problems are sorted, there's yet another hurdle: the infamous [`Internal Error: null` problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000007850-Internal-Error-null-while-running-Scala-Worksheet) when trying to run the `worksheet`. And from what I've observed, once I hit this error, only *restarting* `IntelliJ` overcomes it.

---

Here are my configurations

IDE

```
- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Community Edition)
- Build #IC-173.4548.28, built on January 30, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b11 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Mac OS X 10.13.3
- Scala Plugin Version: 2017.3.11.1
```

Project

```
- Scala 2.11.11
- SBT 1.0.3
- Typesafe Scala Logging "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2"
```

Comment: I've found that the `worksheet` loads the new code after restarting `IntelliJ`. Unless the `worksheet` feature was designed to be useless, I'm missing something.

Comment: I've created [issue SCL-13338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13338) in `JetBrains`' `YouTrack` forums for this problem